# about Facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

May I know can we change the url, image, type, title fields on META fields　when we pressing a button to post it on Facebook? e.g.:

```
 <meta property="og:type"   content="" /> 
 <meta property="og:url"    content="" /> 
 <meta property="og:title"  content="" /> 
 <meta property="og:image"  content="" />
```

it is empty when user enter to the site, and the info will be filled in if you pressing a 'submit' button, I know jquery can do this, but may I know is facebook Open graph accept this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn’t work that way.

Facebook’s scraper will visit the OG objects URL and extract the meta data – so that data has to be delivered by your server, on a request that has no connection with what your user may be seeing in their browser at the moment, and the scraper will also not execute any JavaScript.